# Why Does the DXA Webapp Fill the WebSphere Class Cache to 100%?

Tags: dxa, dxa-2.0, java, cache

We have a DXA 2.0 Java webapp built and deployed on a WebSphere environment.  It runs perfectly fine the majority of the time, however, every 23-25 hours (seemingly regardless of load) our JVM would restart causing an outage.  Upon further investigation we found that the WebSphere class cache was filling up to 100% and the restart would come directly afterward.  We also observed that with the class cache disabled, our server runs as expected.  We are wondering what might be causing the class cache to fill in DXA or if anyone has seen anything similar?

Here are the relevant snippets of our Cache Summary:

```
1SCLTEXTCSUM   Cache Summary
NULL           ------------------


2SCLTEXTCSZ        Cache size                                = 125828520
2SCLTEXTFRB        Free bytes                                = 0
2SCLTEXTRCB        ROMClass bytes                            = 92871044

2SCLTEXTMDA        Metadata bytes                            = 2350520
2SCLTEXTDAS        Class debug area size                     = 10035200
2SCLTEXTDAU        Class debug area % used                   = 99%
2SCLTEXTDAN        Class LineNumberTable bytes               = 4914714
2SCLTEXTDAV        Class LocalVariableTable bytes            = 5120480
NULL
2SCLTEXTNRC        Number ROMClasses                         = 30207
2SCLTEXTNAM        Number AOT Methods                        = 6657
2SCLTEXTNAD        Number AOT Data Entries                   = 1
2SCLTEXTNAH        Number AOT Class Hierarchy                = 2786
2SCLTEXTNAT        Number AOT Thunks                         = 2005
2SCLTEXTNJH        Number JIT Hints                          = 7364
2SCLTEXTNJP        Number JIT Profiles                       = 11167
2SCLTEXTNCP        Number Classpaths                         = 12
2SCLTEXTNUR        Number URLs                               = 220
2SCLTEXTNTK        Number Tokens                             = 0
2SCLTEXTNOJ        Number Java Objects                       = 0
2SCLTEXTNZC        Number Zip Caches                         = 28
2SCLTEXTNJC        Number JCL Entries                        = 0
2SCLTEXTNST        Number Stale classes                      = 0
2SCLTEXTPST        Percent Stale classes                     = 0%
NULL
2SCLTEXTCPF        Cache is 100% full
```